# How to avoid flickering images with keypress?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code where a user has to press 0 to mute the sound or 1 to play the sound of a music piece. If the sound is muted, the image changes and otherwise when the music plays.

```
var audio = new Audio();

window.onload = function geluidMaken() {
    audio.src = "../Geluiden/Achtergrond_Geluid.mp3";
    audio.play();
    audio.loop = true;
    window.addEventListener("keypress", function geluidsKnoppen() {
        var codeGeluid = event.which || event.keyCode;
        if(codeGeluid == 48) {
            var geluidAanKnop = new Image();
            geluidAanKnop.src = "../Afbeeldingen/Sound_Button.png";
            mijnObject.drawImage(geluidAanKnop, (canvas.width/2)-25, 850, geluidAanKnop.width, geluidAanKnop.height);
            audio.muted = true;
        }
        else if(codeGeluid = 49) {
            var geluidAfKnop = new Image();
            geluidAfKnop.src = "../Afbeeldingen/Mute_Button.png";
            mijnObject.drawImage(geluidAfKnop, (canvas.width/2)-25, 850, geluidAfKnop.width, geluidAfKnop.height);
            audio.muted = false;
        }
    });
}
```

I have also a other piece of code where I render all my other functions

```
function tekenenObjecten() {
    mijnObject.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    makenBalkKort();
    makenBal();
    makenMuur();
    makenBord();
```

The images aren't visible on the canvas but when I click on the keys 0 or 1 the images appears and dissapears directly. How to make sure the images stay on the canvas and change when the 0 or 1 is pressed?

Comment: Is there other code that manipulates `mijnObject`?

Comment: @Sumurai8 yes, I try to make a game such as BrickBreaker and my paddle, ball and bricks are all made with mijnObject :). It would be easy to render my function "geluidsKnoppen()" but I don't know if it is possible with a keypress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with a canvas in html5, remember that when you redraw a frame, you remove everything that is on the canvas, then draw everything you want to see in the new frame.

In your keypress handler, you draw the image once. When a new frame is drawn in the other part of your code, the canvas is cleared, and you never redraw it.

What you want to do is probably have a placeholder that is always drawn, then only change it source and let the main loop take care of it.

```
var audioKnop = new Image();
var audioAanSource = "../Afbeeldingen/Sound_Button.png";
var audioMuteSource = "../Afbeeldingen/Mute_Button.png";

function init() {
  audioKnop.src = audioMuteSource;
}

function tekenenObjecten() {
  mijnObject.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  makenBalkKort();
  makenBal();
  makenMuur();
  makenBord();
  maakAudioButton();
}

function maakAudioButton() {
  mijnObject.drawImage(audioKnop, (canvas.width/2)-25, 850, audioKnop.width, audioKnop.height);
}

window.addEventListener("keypress", function () {
  var codeGeluid = event.which || event.keyCode;
  if(codeGeluid == 48) {
    audioKnop.src = audioAanSource;
    audio.muted = true;
  } else if(codeGeluid == 49) {
    audioKnop.src = audioMuteSource;
    audio.muted = false;
  }
});
```